# Simple wrapping dont work

Tags: uv

﻿﻿﻿It's probably silly, but I can't get a simple cube to map.

[This is the file.](https://pasteall.org/blend/19c485d7d6004f2781547851ab5d957e)

Why doesn't the image render over the cube? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your material for your object, you have to plug in an image texture so that you can see your image:

[image]